# What is the proper date format when converting String to Date in Swift

Tags: swift3

The date format that I'm passing my DateFormatter is not working.
Why is the year appearing as the first component of the date when I specify month in the dateFormat?  Why is my am/pm marker in the dateFormat being ignored? Finally, why or how do I correct for time zone?  I didn't specify, yet a different time zone has been used.
Thanks!

```
 if let publishDateString = post["publishDate"] as? String {
                    print("publishDateString is \(publishDateString)") // 2/17/2016 2:49:00 PM
                    let myDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"
                    let dateFromString = myDateFormatter.date(from: publishDateString)!
                    print("My date from string is \(dateFromString)")  // 2016-02-17 19:49:00 +0000
                }
```

Comment: just get your string from the resulting date using DateFormatter also. BTW Date is a point in time and stores no timezone. You need to display it to the user using DateFormatter.

Comment: `let sringFromDate = myDateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString)`